# unable to access a class function from its object instance

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ffmpeg

I'm unable to access a class function from its object instance - the object is being initialized properly and the constructor runs perfectly as well - just not able to explicitly call a function from that class

Code for my FFmpeg class:

```
module.exports = class FFmpeg {
  constructor(rtpParameters) {
    this._rtpParameters = rtpParameters;
    this._process = undefined;
    this._observer = new EventEmitter();
    this._createProcess();
  }

  _createProcess() {
    const sdpString = createSdpText(this._rtpParameters);
    const sdpStream = convertStringToStream(sdpString);

    console.log("createProcess() [sdpString:%s]", sdpString);

    this._process = child_process.spawn("ffmpeg", this._commandArgs);

    if (this._process.stderr) {
      this._process.stderr.setEncoding("utf-8");

      this._process.stderr.on("data", (data) =>
        console.log("ffmpeg::process::data [data:%o]", data)
      );
    }

    if (this._process.stdout) {
      this._process.stdout.setEncoding("utf-8");

      this._process.stdout.on("data", (data) =>
        console.log("ffmpeg::process::data [data:%o]", data)
      );
    }

    this._process.on("message", (message) =>
      console.log("ffmpeg::process::message [message:%o]", message)
    );

    this._process.on("error", (error) =>
      console.error("ffmpeg::process::error [error:%o]", error)
    );

    this._process.once("close", () => {
      console.log("ffmpeg::process::close");
      this._observer.emit("process-close");
    });

    sdpStream.on("error", (error) =>
      console.error("sdpStream::error [error:%o]", error)
    );

    // Pipe sdp stream to the ffmpeg process
    sdpStream.resume();
    sdpStream.pipe(this._process.stdin);
  }

  kill() {
    console.log("kill() [pid:%d]", this._process.pid);
    this._process.kill("SIGINT");
  }

  get _commandArgs() {
    let commandArgs = [
      "-loglevel",
      "debug",
      "-protocol_whitelist",
      "pipe,udp,rtp",
      "-fflags",
      "+genpts",
      "-f",
      "sdp",
      "-i",
      "pipe:0",
    ];

    commandArgs = commandArgs.concat(this._videoArgs);
    commandArgs = commandArgs.concat(this._audioArgs);

    commandArgs = commandArgs.concat([
      "-flags",
      "+global_header",
      `${RECORD_FILE_LOCATION_PATH}/${this._rtpParameters.fileName}.webm`,
    ]);

    console.log("commandArgs:%o", commandArgs);

    return commandArgs;
  }

  get _videoArgs() {
    return ["-map", "0:v:0", "-c:v", "copy"];
  }

  get _audioArgs() {
    return [
      "-map",
      "0:a:0",
      "-strict", // libvorbis is experimental
      "-2",
      "-c:a",
      "copy",
    ];
  }
};
```

My implementation of creation of this class' instance:

```
async startRecord() {
    if (this._isRecording) return;

    this._isRecording = true;
    let recordInfo = {};
    const joinedPeers = this._getJoinedPeers();
    for (const peer of joinedPeers) {
      for (const producer of peer.data.producers.values()) {
        recordInfo[producer.kind] = await this.publishProducerRtpStream(
          peer,
          producer
        );
        recordInfo.fileName = Date.now().toString();

        peer.data.process = this.getProcess(recordInfo);
        setTimeout(async () => {
          console.log(peer.data.process);
          // I want to call peer.data.process.kill() HERE!
        }, 4000);
      }
    }
  }
  async getProcess(recordInfo) {
    return new FFmpeg(recordInfo);
  }
```

I want to call the kill() function in FFmpeg and it shows undefined. Really don't understand how.

Here's the log of the object instance (which doesn't have the "kill" function mentioned anywhere and maybe hence shows that .kill() is undefined)

[image: console logging the object created from the class FFmpeg (new FFmpeg)]

Would greatly appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

awaited the creation of the object into a variable, and called the functions on that variable: I'd gotten a Promsie<>